# Require multiple Tag names for Azure Resource Group

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I have the following use case: I would like to have Azure policy, requiring to have two mandatory tags: **Environment** and **Project** for **resource groups**. There should not be the possibility to create a new resource group without those two tags and the already created resource groups, that do not have the two tags, should show as non-compliant. So far it sounds like a straight forward scenario, but I am not getting the expected result and it is getting harder and harder to keep my sanity, so please advise.

I have reviewed multiple threads in Stack Overflow, as well as this Microsoft article: [How to build an audit Azure Policy with multiple parameters](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/how-to-build-an-audit-azure-policy-with-multiple-parameters/ba-p/1866062)
.

I use the following code:

```json
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
        },
        {
          "field": "tags['Environment']",
          "exists": "false"
        },
        {
          "field": "tags['Project']",
          "exists": "false"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

**Note**: I have removed the parameters in the process of troubleshooting, and replaced them with values for simplification. The result was the same when using parameters', instead of explicit values.

My understanding is that **allOf** should act as a **logical AND** and should **require all the conditions to be in place** - To be a resource group, to have tag Environment and to have tag Project.

So what is the result? When creating a new resource group, the validation does not allow you to continue without providing tags for Environment and Project:
[image]

**Note**: You may see that there is the same policy name for the tag requirements and this is the only policy assignment ... everywhere! This is my personal test tenant, so there is no possibility for other policy assignments that I am not aware of.

The thing is that it allows me to continue further with only one tag provided:

- Only Environment

[image: Only Environment]

- Only Project

[image: Only Project]

If we look at the compliance status, you may see that the resource group is marked as **compliant** by the policy:

[image]

but it has only a **single tag - Project**, without the tag Environment... and still marked as compliant.

[image]

So after this long walk-trough, my question is - **How to make mandatory to have those two tags - Environment and Project**. There could be other tags, but those two should be required and not allowing new resource groups to be created without providing them, and the old resource groups to be marked as non-compliant, if both are missing.

What I am missing that it does not work, as expected?

I have also used the code from the article ... 1:1 ... copy - paste, again I was able to continue only with single tag.

Please support.

I have followed other examples from Stack overflow, as official Microsoft article. Even the suggested example from the Microsoft article was not working as expected, or at least based on my expectation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **AllOf** condition here indicates to the policy engine to detect an uncompliance resource if all conditions are met. Meaning that:

1. You are currently scanning a RG
2. The current RG does not have **Environment** tag
3. The current RG does not have a **Project** tag

We can phrase it as : "My item is uncompliant if this a RG which does not have an Environment **AND** does not have a Tag project".

If any of this condition is met (example one tag exist), the resource is then tagged as **Compliant** because it does not meet your overall condition.

You want to add an AnyOf condition here to make sure it breaks if one or the other tag does not exist. To phrase it the following way : "My item is uncompliant if this a RG which does not have an Environment **OR** does not have a Tag project".

Code:

```json
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
        },
        {
          "anyOf": [
            {
              "field": "tags['Environment']",
              "exists": "false"
            },
            {
              "field": "tags['Project']",
              "exists": "false"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

Comment: Ooooh man, it is so obvious now it just cannot be unseen. :D
Thanks for the support!